# 10% dip in February for metrics that count?

Tags: count-data, histogram

February usually has 28 days, unlike it's neighbors January and March which have 31.

It seems that most countable things will exhibit, on average, a 10% dip in February for the missing 3 days.

This isn't a matter of pure statistics, but it's something I just noticed. Is this known? Is it ever adjusted for charts?

Comment: Anything that is seasonally adjusted should successfully adjust for this. If you were actually doing a histogram with frequency density you could have bar width proportional to length of month and height proportional to count per day.

Comment: If the countable things occur disproportionately either on weekdays or at weekends then it gets a bit more complicated.  February, when it has 28 days, must have 20 weekdays and 4 weekends, whereas a month of 31 days may have between 21 and 23 weekdays and 4, 4.5 or 5 weekends.